Is possible to use Sign In With Apple without an actual app on AppStore?
Is possible to use Sign In With Apple on a website without an actual counterpart app on AppStore?

Yes, you can use Sign in with Apple JS. You do need a paid developer account in order to set up the required certificates and identifiers but you do not need to publish an app.

Thank you. From the far I know you need to associate the certificate to a Bundle ID. So you suggest to create a bundle id, make the association but not publish the app, right?

Yes. That should work
